# Tailor one string vector to exact size of other

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I have text data in column `Segments` and their corresponding text-tag combinations in `Q_c7_collpsd`. However, `Q_c7_collpsd` is longer than `Segments`. My task is to trim `Q_c7_collpsd` to the exact length and content of `Segments`. (Another difficulty is that `Segments` contains special characters, which are not found in `Q_c7_collpsd`).

This is **what I've tried so far**;  it only partly works (wrong assigments are marked with **...*)

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%

  mutate(
    # trim whitespace:
    Segments = trimws(Segments),
    # correct "n 't" to "n't":
    Segments = str_replace_all(Segments, "(?<=n)\\s(?='t)", ""),
    # separate clitics from host:
    Segments = str_replace_all(Segments, "n't", " n't")) %>%
  # split into Segment_type and Utterance:
  separate(Segments, into = c("Segment_type", "Utterance"), sep = ":\\s") %>%
  # remove special characters:
  mutate(Utterance_Clean = str_remove_all(Utterance, "(?![\\s'])\\W")) %>%
  # remove rows where Utterance_Clean is digits:
  filter(!str_detect(Utterance_Clean, "^\\d+$")) %>%

  # create id:
  group_by(Q_c7_collpsd) %>%
  mutate(id = rleid(Sequ, Utterance)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  # split into individual word-tag combinations:
  separate_rows(Q_c7_collpsd, sep = "\\s") %>%
  separate(Q_c7_collpsd, into = c("w", "c7"), sep = "_") %>%
  
  # split into individual words:
  separate_rows(Utterance_Clean, sep = "\\s") %>%
  group_by(Sequ, id) %>%
  # keep only rows where w == Utterance_Clean:
  filter(w == Utterance_Clean) %>%
  # combine w and c7 tag back again:
  mutate(w_c7 = str_c(w, c7, sep = "_")) %>%
  # put splitted elemments back together:
  summarise(across(c(Segment_type, Utterance), first),
            w_c7 = str_c(w_c7, collapse = " "))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   Sequ [2]
   Sequ    id Segment_type Utterance                     w_c7                                                        
  <dbl> <int> <chr>        <chr>                         <chr>                                                       
1     1     1 tcu_noQ      °[o::h my God]                oh_UH my_APPGE God_NP1 **my_APPGE*                             
2     1     2 tcu_pol      you have n't seen my place?°= **my_APPGE* you_PPY have_VH0 n't_XX seen_VVN my_APPGE place_NN1
3     2     1 tcu_decl     [but you] use leggings¿       but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 leggings_NN2                        
4     2     2 frg          or                            or_CC                                                       
5     2     3 tcu_decl     no?                           no_UH                                                       
6     2     4 tcu_noQ      [(I do n't know)]             I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_VVI
```

**Desired result:**

```
   Sequ    id Segment_type Utterance                     w_c7                                                        
  <dbl> <int> <chr>        <chr>                         <chr>                                                       
1     1     1 tcu_noQ      °[o::h my God]                oh_UH my_APPGE God_NP1                            
2     1     2 tcu_pol      you have n't seen my place?°= you_PPY have_VH0 n't_XX seen_VVN my_APPGE place_NN1
3     2     1 tcu_decl     [but you] use leggings¿       but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 leggings_NN2                        
4     2     2 frg          or                            or_CC                                                       
5     2     3 tcu_decl     no?                           no_UH                                                       
6     2     4 tcu_noQ      [(I do n't know)]             I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_VVI
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sequ = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2), 
  Segments = c("tcu_noQ: °[o::h my God] ", "tcu_pol: you haven't seen my place?°=", "tcu_decl: [but you] use leggings¿","frg: or","pause: 0.485","tcu_decl: no?","tcu_noQ: [(I don 't know)]"),
  Q_c7_collpsd = c("oh_UH my_APPGE God_NP1 you_PPY have_VH0 n't_XX seen_VVN my_APPGE place_NN1", "oh_UH my_APPGE God_NP1 you_PPY have_VH0 n't_XX seen_VVN my_APPGE place_NN1", 
                   "but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 leggings_NN2 or_CC no_UH I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_VVI","but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 leggings_NN2 or_CC no_UH I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_VVI","but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 leggings_NN2 or_CC no_UH I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_VVI","but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 leggings_NN2 or_CC no_UH I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_VVI","but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 leggings_NN2 or_CC no_UH I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_VVI"))
```

Comment: Just a note: `"(?![\\s'])\\W"` is better written as `"[^\\w\\s']"`

Comment: Thanks for asking. The requirements are actually simple: after removing the special characters in `Segments` I only want to be able to exactly cut out from `Q_c7_collpsd`that substring that corresponds to the respective `Segment`. For example, for  `Segment` "°[o::h my God]" I want to cut out "oh_UH my_APPGE God_NP1"  from the corresponding `Q_c7_collpsd` "oh_UH my_APPGE God_NP1 you_PPY have_VH0 n't_XX seen_VVN my_APPGE place_NN1"

Comment: Ok Give me some time, I'll do it.  The problem is in words that are not unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do.

Explanation:  Upto the step marked with multiple `#####...` everything is same.  If you'll see output there, we have cleaned utterance in a single row for each `Sequ`.  So I proposed creating an ID there for each cleaned utterance.  Now our job is to find relevant `Q7_c_collpsd`.  So instead of using `separate_rows` and `Separate` once again I used `purrr::map_chr` which extracts `w_c7`.

Further explanation of `map_chr` portion

- first argument is split `Q7_c_collpsd` by a space ( in the same way you were using `separate_rows`)
- second argument id `ID` for mapping
- function part is just extracting `ID`th part of first argument.  Just like you were doing in filter portion.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    # trim whitespace:
    Segments = trimws(Segments),
    # correct "n 't" to "n't":
    Segments = str_replace_all(Segments, "(?<=n)\\s(?='t)", ""),
    # separate clitics from host:
    Segments = str_replace_all(Segments, "n't", " n't")
  ) %>%
  # split into Segment_type and Utterance:
  separate(Segments,
           into = c("Segment_type", "Utterance"),
           sep = ":\\s") %>%
  # remove special characters:
  mutate(Utterance_Clean = str_remove_all(Utterance, "(?![\\s'])\\W")) %>%
  # remove rows where Utterance_Clean is digits:
  filter(!str_detect(Utterance_Clean, "^\\d+$")) %>%
  separate_rows(Utterance_Clean, sep = "\\s") %>% 
  #####################################################
  # Create ID here
  mutate(id = row_number(), .by = Sequ) %>% 
  mutate(Q_new = map2_chr(str_split(Q_c7_collpsd, "\\s"), id,~ .x[[.y]])) %>% #View
  summarise(
    w_c7 = str_c(Q_new, collapse = " "),
    .by = c(Sequ, Segment_type, Utterance)
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>    Sequ Segment_type Utterance                     w_c7                         
#>   <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                         <chr>                        
#> 1     1 tcu_noQ      °[o::h my God]                oh_UH my_APPGE God_NP1       
#> 2     1 tcu_pol      you have n't seen my place?°= you_PPY have_VH0 n't_XX seen…
#> 3     2 tcu_decl     [but you] use leggings¿       but_CCB you_PPY use_VV0 legg…
#> 4     2 frg          or                            or_CC                        
#> 5     2 tcu_decl     no?                           no_UH                        
#> 6     2 tcu_noQ      [(I do n't know)]             I_PPIS1 do_VD0 n't_XX know_V…
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

PS:  `dplyr` 1.1.0 onwards has now gained a function `consecutive_id()` which works exactly like `data.table::rleid()`, So,  no need to load that package just for one function, which hasn't been used in revised answer anyways.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Can you perhaps explain or even unpack into more lines this step `mutate(Q_new = map2_chr(str_split(Q_c7_collpsd, "\\s"), id,~ .x[[.y]]))`?

Comment: Can it be that `map2_chr` keeps a record of the list elements (created by `str_split`) and that the mapping proceeds via correspondances between this index and the vector `id`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, Sorry for late response, but I have since explained it. May be it helps.